# Selecting only the clicked element that was added to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, click

I've been making this web app to test out JQuery a bit.  It just adds elements to the DOM.  I've been having trouble with the click events for the newly added elements.  I want to be able to only change the one that I clicked on instead of the whole group of elements.

Here's a link to a demo [video](http://sendvid.com/o379tcqn).

Here's what I have for my code:

```
    var main = function() {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);

    $('.post-btn').click(function() {
        var text = $('.status-box').val();
        $('<li>').text(text).fadeIn(600).prependTo('.posts');
        $('.status-box').val('');
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        $('.counter').text(140);
    });

    $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
        $('.counter').css('color', '#404040');
        var characters = $('.status-box').val().length;
        var charactersleft = 140 - characters;
        $('.counter').text(charactersleft);

        if(charactersleft < 0) {
            $('.post-btn').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.counter').css('color', 'red');
        }

        else if(charactersleft === 140) {
            $('.post-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }

        else {
            $('.post-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    $('.delete-btn').click(function() {
        $('.selected').fadeOut(300);
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });

    /**
    * Click event starts here
    **/
    $('.posts').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
        $('.posts li').css('background-color', 'lightgray').addClass('selected');
        $('.delete-btn').prop('disabled', false);
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

I understand that that `$('.posts li')` applies to all of the created elements, I just don't know how to make it apply to only the one that I've clicked on.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)`.

```
$('.posts').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgray').addClass('selected');
  ...
```

Comment: It's funny how I can mess up something so simple.  It seems as though I may have been overthinking it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this line:

```
$('.posts').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
        $('.posts li').css('background-color', 'lightgray').addClass('selected');
```

with this one:

```
$('.posts').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
 $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgray').addClass('selected');
```

**$(this)** instead of **$('.posts li')**